# devise makes a db call on `authenticate_user!`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

we use `before_filter :authenticate_user`

I was wondering about the following code:

> ```
>   def serialize_from_session(key, salt)
>       record = to_adapter.get(key)
>       record if record && record.authenticatable_salt == salt
>     end
> ```

Its in `devise-3.1.0/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb`
Does devise make call to database for every request? or am I reading something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

It will read the stored user data (user ID and authentication salt) from the session, then verify that a user in the database matches this stored data, by performing a lookup. The second part of that is what this code is doing.

Comment: why? If something about a user changes between requests (eg. someone else deletes their account, or the user is attempting to tamper with their session data) that needs to be checked on each load. So the user record is loaded up and verified. It's a very minor overhead.

Comment: if something changes between request.. eg delete account - oki agreed but I think there can be better ways like resetting the session ?
user cannot tamper the session data since its digested